# Bootstrap HTML5 Title with border and small text like fieldset but no fieldset/legend

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, panel, fieldset

I am building bootstrap based web and I am trying to make title inside of a frame with text attached in the middle of bottom border and still be responsive. Small text on small devices can go in multiple rows, or even go inside the box.

All I could do is
[image: this].
 And I want to do it like [image: this].

I hope someone already done this and/or could help me doing it.

Thanks in advance.

**One big detail is it should be completely transparent so it can go over a backround picture.**

**And it is much differend than fieldset because the "legend" is on bottom.**

Comment: Can you provide us the code you've tried (fiddle would be great)

Comment: here is [https://jsfiddle.net/nwfpkLkc/2/](https://jsfiddle.net/nwfpkLkc/2/), I tried with navbar classes but didin't make it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

[See fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nwfpkLkc/4/)

**CSS:**

```
.navbar-brand {
  margin: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-top: 8px solid #ffffff;
  padding: 5px 32px 0px 32px;
  line-height: 1.08333333;
  height: auto;
}
.navbar-brand:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: -8px;
  top: -8px;
  width: 8px;
  bottom: 12px;
  background: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-brand:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  right: -8px;
  top: -8px;
  width: 8px;
  bottom: 12px;
  background: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-brand a:hover,
.navbar-brand a:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.navbar-header + h3 {
  margin-top: 61px;
}
.navbar-header {
  text-align: center;
}
.small-lines:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: -40px;
  height: 8px;
  bottom: 12px;
  width: 8%;
  background: #ffffff;
}
.small-lines:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  right: -40px;
  height: 8px;
  bottom: 12px;
  width: 8%;
  background: #ffffff;
}
.small-lines1:before {
  width: 38%;
  background: #009fb6;
}
.small-lines1:after {
  width: 38%;
  background: #009fb6;
}
.navbar-brand a{
    font-size: 48px;
}
.container{
    margin-top: 150px;
}

small {
    line-height: 1.2;
    font-size: 24px;
    letter-spacing: 4.8px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
    <body style="background: black">
    <header class="">  
        <div class="container text-center">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <h1 class="navbar-brand ">
                    <a href="./">BIG TITLE ONE<br>
                        <small class="small-lines">Here comes small text</small>
                    </a>
                </h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    </body>
```

Comment: I knew how to do it that way, but I need it to be transparent, without background. So it can go over the background.

Comment: Will you use that on a complicated surface or just on a plain color? If so you can just make both colors to be same as background. But I suppose you will use it on complex background scenarios. So. You may prefer using svg instead.

Comment: I would use it on background photo or even video. I can't use this background trick, svg is always an option but it is not that accessible.

Comment: [here](http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/54950.html) I found a similar example.

Comment: @dippas this is not a duplicate, I don't want to use fieldset, and I need it to be responsive. There is no q/a matching mine.

Comment: @EmirhanÖzlen this is much much closer. Thanks, now I found the idea to make it perfect. Thanks again.